# check if save button is clicked in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Im trying to add decorators (eg. adding a suffix to a file) Whenever a save button click happens within a file that is currently open, I search but is having a  hard time figuring it out Heres my code

```
public void decorate(Object resource, IDecoration decoration) {

    if () //I'm having trouble with this check
    {
    decoration.addSuffix("--Modified");
    }
    }
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is an IEditorPartListener that listens to if editor is "dirty" meaning unsaved or not dirty meaning saved you need to get a reference to the IEditorPart and add the correct listener than you can decorate you navigator as you please.