# How to check if save button is clicked in Eclipse Plugin development?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704868/check-if-save-button-is-clicked-in-eclipse-plugin-development), but I am specifically looking for a way to check that the save button in Eclipse was clicked, not that the editor is being saved.

Comment: There are various ways of handing this so you need to tell us what you want to do.

Comment: In its most basic form, I want to create a dialog reminding the user that the keyboard shortcut to save is Ctrl + S whenever the user clicks on the save button.

Comment: Why are you trying to annoy your users?

Comment: It was just the simplest example I could find to explain what I want to do. I am not planning on actually having a dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IExecutionListener` to listen to the File Save command. Something like:

```java
ICommandService commandSvc = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getAdapter(ICommandService.class);
Command saveCommand = commandSvc.getCommand(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_SAVE);
saveCommand.addExecutionListener(new IExecutionListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void preExecute(final String commandId, final ExecutionEvent event)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void postExecuteSuccess(final String commandId, final Object returnValue)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void postExecuteFailure(final String commandId, final ExecutionException exception)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void notHandled(final String commandId, final NotHandledException exception)
    {
    }
  });
```

`IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_SAVE` is the standard constant containing the file save command id.

The `ExecutionEvent` parameter has a `getTrigger` method which returns to object that caused the command to run. It looks like this will be a `MenuItem` if the 'File > Save' menu caused the command to run.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this only tells me that the save command was executed, right?

In order to check that the save button was clicked, I would also have to listen for a click?

Comment: The `ExecutionEvent` argument has a `getTrigger` which tells you where the save command came from - updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. More specifically, the `getTrigger()` method returns an `Object` which has a runtime class of `Event`. You can get the `Widget` from that `Event` and check that it is an instance of `MenuItem`.